# How can I account for range restriction when meta-analytically aggregating differences based upon bounded measures such as mean proportions?

Tags: proportion, meta-analysis, effect-size

**Background and Problem**

In the past, I have read or conducted meta-analyses that aggregate effects based upon mean proportions. For example, in a typical psychological experiment dealing with human memory each subject might be asked to study a list of 20 words split across two conditions (e.g., read aloud or read silently). A subsequent test of their memory for those words would produce a proportion for each condition (e.g., 7/10 = .7 and 5/10 = .5), and the difference would be considered the effect of interest (e.g., .7 - .5 = .2). Importantly, a proportion is calculated for each subject and only the mean and standard deviation of those individual proportions are reported. Meta-analyses of such data tend to use the standardized mean difference between these conditions as the metric of interest. However, such an approach ignores the fact that the proportions are bounded to vary between 0 and 1. Further, I have seen effect sizes estimated for comparisons in cases wherein overall performance was perilously close to ceiling (e.g., p ~ .95) or floor (e.g., p ~ .05).

**My Questions:**

With this in mind, I would like to ask:

1. Can one account for range restriction when meta-analytically aggregating differences based upon measures such as mean proportions?
2. Is it meaningful to calculate the standardized mean difference for a bounded variable when overall performance is close to one of the boundaries (e.g., p > .85)?

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I am not sure whether you can apply methods such as those from Cragg or Heckman to aggregate data. If there are many studies, and individual point effects are not close to 1, then pooling SMD might be acceptably robust in my opinion. I look forward though to see whether anybody can provide a good analytical answer.

Comment: If what is reported is the difference between them (0.2 in your example) then presumably the range is -1 to +1? Or is all you have the proportions in each condition? If there is a tradition of sharing data in your field perhaps writing to the authors is going to be the best way forward.

Comment: @mdewey Sadly, data sharing is uncommon in my field. However, to answer your other question the range of the difference itself would be -1 to 1, although in practice such differences are most often between -.5 and .5. Also, the condition means are more commonly reported. This question pertains more to whether it is problematic to calculate SMD from condition summary statistics (e.g., mean proportions for each condition) when the DV itself is bounded and performance in the individual points is near a boundary. I may try to undertake a simulation in the coming days to check on this empirically.

Comment: In that case I would have thought the differences would be better behaved than the original proportions.